# Autofac AutofacControllerConfiguration fails with HttpControllerDescriptorTracer null reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm attempting to configure my Web API service using Autofac 3.1.0.

I've added the "marker" attribute to the controller:

```
[AutofacControllerConfiguration]
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{
    // ... snip ...
}
```

And registered it:

```
// controllers
container.RegisterApiControllers(typeof (DocumentController).Assembly);
container.RegisterApiControllers(typeof (WorkflowController).Assembly);

// security
container.RegisterType<OAuthTokenManager>().As<IOAuthTokenManager>();
container.RegisterType<OAuthAccessToken>().As<IOAuthAccessToken>();
container.RegisterType<LegacyTypeAwareIdentifierFactory<IOAuthAccessToken>>().As<ITypeAwareIdentifierFactory<IOAuthAccessToken>>();
container.RegisterType<OAuthTokenExtractor>().As<ITokenExtractor>();
container.RegisterType<OAuthTokenValidator>().As<ITokenValidator>();
container.RegisterType<TokenHelper>().As<ITokenHelper>();

container.Register(x =>
{
    if (x.IsRegistered<HttpRequestMessage>())
    {
        var httpRequestMethod = x.Resolve<HttpRequestMessage>();

        var tokenHelper = x.Resolve<ITokenHelper>();
        var token = tokenHelper.GetToken(httpRequestMethod);

        var connectionContext = x.Resolve<ISqlServerConnectionContext>();
        connectionContext.Token = token;

        return token ?? new NullMinimalSecurityToken();
    }

    return new NullMinimalSecurityToken();
}).As<IMinimalSecurityToken>().InstancePerApiRequest();

container.RegisterType<SecurityTokenAuthorization>()
    .AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterFor<DocumentController>()
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
container.RegisterType<SecurityTokenAuthorization>()
    .AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterFor<WorkflowController>()
    .InstancePerApiRequest();

container.Register(c =>
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppSettingsNames.DatabaseConnection];
    var newConnectionContext = new SqlServerConnectionContext(connectionString) {ProductID = productId};
    newConnectionContext.Open();

    return newConnectionContext;
    }).As<ISqlServerConnectionContext>().As<IConnectionContext>().InstancePerApiRequest().InstancePerApiControllerType(typeof(DocumentController));
```

I end up with the following error:

```
{
"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
"ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException",
"StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerDescriptorTracer.get_Properties()\r\n   at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacControllerConfigurationAttribute.Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor..ctor(HttpConfiguration configuration, String controllerName, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerSelectorTracer.System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
}
```

If I simply remove the "marker" attribute, my service works but that isn't really a viable solution since I have 2 controllers, and need to supply the correct database connection to each. I'd be happy to implement an alternate solution, but after fighting to get to this point for an entire day, I'm drawing a blank at the moment.

Have I missed something in using that feature, or can somebody suggest an alternative?

Comment: I put together an app with a controller marked with the attribute; a simple per-request and per-controller-type dependency; and a simple operation... and I can't reproduce the error. Something else must be going on in your app - some other service change happening, some other config going on that matters. Looking in Reflector at `HttpControllerDescriptorTracer.Properties` it simply passes through to the current controller descriptor - nothing I can see that would throw an exception. Any more details you can provide?

Comment: I'm sure there are more details I could provide. I'm trying to localize the problem now. We've got about 100 lines of registrations (so probably ~60 components). Obviously it wouldn't be helpful to post all of those along with their source. I'm also looking into an issue where my IAutofacAuthorizationFilter isn't being called for every request. Possibly related.

Comment: Never mind about the Auth filter. That was a missing builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

Comment: Something you might want to check out - the list of service overrides (if any) on `HttpConfiguration`. I see you expanded your list of Autofac registrations, but there's a chance the problem is just being exposed via Autofac and that the real issue is in a standard Web API service being customized. For example, if you have a custom `IHttpControllerSelector` that is doing something with the controller descriptors, that might result in the problem.

Comment: Other than examining the config after doing a container.Build(), is there somewhere else I can check? I've eliminated any code that looked like it might have registered something (there was one ApiControllerActionSelector, so I removed the registration since it's servicing a different area than I'm currently testing), but there's no difference in the error.

Comment: I should also point out that I'm converting working code from Ninject to Autofac and haven't changed anything other than the Auth filter since Ninject doesn't support injecting those in Web API. That changed class is one part that _is_ working.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other tips. It sounds like your app is sufficiently complex that it won't be easy to diagnose without a lot more info or interactive debugging. You should be able to step into the Autofac and Web API source, maybe try that? Break on the exception and inspect what's going on?

Comment: Yeah. That's going to be my plan for tomorrow. I've been avoiding the Web API source, but might need to delve into that also. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Apparently I'm an idiot (partially). I had in WebApiConfig.cs config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing(). Removing that allows my service to function, however there's still an issue if I ever want to enable tracing. I'll see if I can repro the issue tomorrow with a simpler setup.